# Android studio:java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry error while running the app

Tags: android, android-build

I am getting this error in my Android Project when i run the app.

`Error:Execution failed for task :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug.
 com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaj.class`

**Here is my `build.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.akapoor.kiittimetabletest1"
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id: "6cebaxxx-xxxx-xxxx-89af-55fbddb523ea",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "4283878xxx"]
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 5
        versionName "2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.pushbots:pushbots-lib:2.0.13@aar'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'

    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"
}
```

I have tried solutions posted on other stackoverflow answers but none was working for me. Please check the code. 
Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Use actual version numbers, please, not pluses

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"
```

Make sure all versions match

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
```

(And [your volley library is deprecated](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley))